# How do I make it so Mongo runs automatically all the time on my Azure server?

Tags: mongodb, azure

I have two Azure virtual machines. On one I have a Mongo server, on the other I just have a service I created which listens to Twitters streaming API and filters tweets.

Neither of these two services work unless I manually activate them and keep my console window open. For example, to run Mongo I need to ssh into my virtual machine and type: `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`. This starts the Mongo server successfully, but if at anytime I close my browser the service stops.

I believe the reason this is occurring is because when I login the system is allocating me a process by which I can navigate around the system and perform commands. When I type `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` I believe I am using that process to run Mongo. I am not sure how to make Mongo run without doing this though.

How do I make it so Mongo runs automatically all the time on my Azure server?

EDIT:

I tried running Mongo as a daemon but I receive an error:

```
$ mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log

>>>about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
>>>forked process: 63470
>>>ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
```

Comment: You want to run it as a daemon: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#start-mongod-as-a-daemon

Comment: Thanks; Updated posts to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has nothing to do with Azure; it's all about how you install MongoDB.

If you install mongodb as a service, via apt-get (or whatever other means your version of linux requires), then it will run independent of you being logged in. You shouldn't be running an always-on service through your command shell.

Here are [instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) for installing under Ubuntu. You'll see that, once you set up the prerequisite public key and list file, you then run:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

You can then start and stop the service via

```
sudo service mongod start
```

and

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable mongo to autostart on boot by typing this command in your console:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

Then test it by this command:

```
sudo service mongod status
```